# Unit test for a header created inside controller

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, controller

In my Spring Boot application, I'm adding a header inside my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/people", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Person>> systems(Pageable pageable) {
    Page people = peopleService.getPeopleSystems(pageable);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("CustomHeader1", String.valueOf(people.getTotalElements()));
    headers.add("CustomHeader2", String.valueOf(people.getSize()));
    return new ResponseEntity<List<People>>(people.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The header contains the quantity of people which is obtained inside controller.
The code works as expected, but isn't testable.

The test class roughly could be like this:

```
       @Test
public void test_header() throws Exception {

    PeopleService pepleService = mock(PeopleService.class);
    Pageable pageable = mock(Pageable.class);
    Page<Person> page = mock(Page.class);

    when(pepleService.getPeopleSystems(pageable)).thenReturn(page);
    when(page.getTotalElements()).thenReturn((long) 2000);
    when(page.getSize()).thenReturn(10);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/people")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(header().stringValues("CustomHeader1"));
}
```

The test fails at line

```
headers.add("CustomHeader1", String.valueOf(people.getTotalElements()));
```

with NPE exception.

So my question is how to make my controller testable, or how to refactor the code to get rid of creating the new HttpHeaders() inside my method.
Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to inject `HTTPHeader` as a Spring Bean instead of creating a new object every time? In that way, you can mock it out easily.

Comment: Looks like there are some errors in your `@Test` method: you are mocking `when(people.getContent())` method, but `people` is a `List`. The same with `String.valueOf(people.getTotalElements())`. This code shouldn't even compile

Comment: Didn't find where you set ```peopleService``` mock into controller under test and provides a results for ```peopleService.getPeopleSystems``` call. NPE here most likely happend because ```getPeopleSystems``` returns null and ```people(null).getTotalElements()```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out that all what I needed was to indicate that the class was instance of Pagable.class. Here is the working test:

```
   Page<Person> page = new PageImpl<>(new ArrayList<>());
   when(pepleService.getPeopleSystems(any(Pageable.class))).thenReturn(page);
   mockMvc.perform(get("/people")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(header().string("CustomHeader1", "2000"));
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to mock `peopleService` and then mock method `peopleService.getPeopleSystems(pageable)` to return mock of `Page`.
   Then you need to mock methods `people.getTotalElements()` and `people.getSize()` to return proper values.
2. `HttpHeaders headers = mock(HttpHeaders.class)` this should not work because new object is created in method.